# Verify CNAME and dns routing

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I have a server my-main-server.company.com where clients connect to

http://my-main-server.company.com/public

I created a CNAME for it my-server-cname.company.com.

But clients fail to connect at http://my-server-cname.company.com/public

I verified

```
host -al company.com | grep my-main-server
my-main-server.company.com. 3600 IN A   172.xx.210.xxx
my-server-sname.company.com. 3600 IN    CNAME   my-mainserver.company.com.
```

Some more debugging and I realized that this is a machine specific issue. The routing works on other machins but not on mine

Machine details:

I am on a Mac OSx 10.11 Capitan
I tried flushing the dns as follows

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

and

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder; say DNS cache flushed
```

But still cant get to these two CNAMES

Pinging the cname gives me the following kind of output

```
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1156 ttl=64 time=0.084 ms
```

Comment: Don't you need a dot at the end of the target of the CNAME? `my-mainserver.company.com.` rather than just `my-mainserver.company.com`

Comment: Yes, yes you do. That'll teach me how to read.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: error message is "site cant be reached"

Comment: Ah - the fact that ping shows a response from 127.0.0.1 is interesting. Do you have entries for those hosts in the hosts file on your local machine? (`/etc/hosts`). I'm not sure if OS-X uses the plain text file or if there's something smarter managing local hosts entries.

Comment: What does `dscacheutil -q host -a name my-mainserver.company.com.` give? (possibly try with and without the trailing dot).

Comment: umm it gives me the IP of the main server, whats special about the 127.0.0.1?

Comment: I got it to work! you were right the /etc/hosts had hardcoded values for the CNAME in question! Thank you so much for pointing me to the right direction!!!!